# Why use the term "arbitrary"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, soft-question

At the beginning of proofs, mathematicians will often write something like:

- Let $x$ be an arbitrary integer

I understand that the point of this statement is to get the reader of the proof to think about "a new symbol $x$ which represents one of the integers, although the specific integer is unspecified". Because the specific integer is unspecified, nothing will be assumed about the object represented by $x$ throughout the proof, except that it is an  integer. So the proof will apply for all integers.

The above is discussed here: [Question about how to interpret arbitrary elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3954362/question-about-how-to-interpret-arbitrary-elements)

My question is "Why is the term arbitrary used to invoke the above ideas?". This is my guess.

The term "arbitrary" generally means "done without any reasoning or logic". So when a mathematician says "Let $x$ be an arbitrary integer", they are saying "Let $x$ be an integer, where the integer is chosen without any reasoning or logic". Because the integer is chosen withou any reasoning, it is unknown / unspecified. So a reader  will then think about "a new symbol $x$ which represents one of the integers, although the specific integer is unspecified".

Am I correct in understanding why the term "arbitrary" is used?

Thank you for your time and please feel free to elaborate.

Comment: Yes, "arbitrary" here just means $x\in \mathbb Z$ without restrictions.

Comment: The word "arbitrary" is supposed to emphasize that $x$ could be any integer. But I almost never use the word arbitrary myself. I would just say "Let $x$ be an integer."

Answer (score 5):

Yes, "arbitrary" is just a context clue to the reader. It reminds the reader that when we introduce $x$, we're not assuming any particular features about it beyond those explicitly stated (e.g. that $x$ is an integer). At the formal level this is totally unnecessary, but for readers new to proofs it can help the intuition.

(Incidentally, note that [one should not use "random" in this context!](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2529446/28111))